@media print move element to the last page
On a website I have an img-carousel and carousel-indicators which are basically img-thumbnails. I want to create a print-version where the structure is

div.one (carousel) - only the currently active image should be printed
div.three
div.four
div.one (carousel-indicators) - now here i want all other thumbnails to be printed

Is there any way to say like "print an element at a different position on the printed version"? It seems like :last_page selector doesn't work anymore.
example code:
<div class="one">
    <div class="carousel">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="two">
...two...
</div>
<div class="three">
...three...
</div>
<div class="four">
...four...
</div>


@media print {
    @page {
      margin: 1rem !important;
    }
    .two {
      display: none;
    }
  }

I tried using jsPDF and html2pdf so I could move the items using javascript. But I couldn't get those libs really working and i feel like the amount of time I need would exceed everyting.

You can't alter the structure of an HTML file with CSS. Consider adding a div.five which shows the thumbnails only on print and is hidden by default

Yeah thought about that. Gonna have to check the page size then. I guess I'll give it a try.

"only the currently active image should be printed" - that should probably be a given already, unless you (or the carousel component itself) applied specific print styles that make it display something else. "I tried using jsPDF and html2pdf so I could move the items using javascript." - are you trying to create a PDF, or is this just about normal printing? If the latter, then I don't see a need to involve any such complex libraries. [...]

[...] Cloning the .carousel-indicators element once and appending it after .four should get you all the image thumbnails, and then you'd only have to connect it with the event system of your carousel, so that the thumbnail for the currently active slides gets hidden in there.

@CBroe I thought about creating a PDF as well as just creating a print version. The goal is to print the website in a different layout then shown in a browser. And printing means either open printer dialog or save it as PDF. Cloning the images does work.
